# seeking hints for correct escaping of sed commands WITHIN yaml

Tags: centos, text-processing, sed, yaml

I am having a hard time finding the issue why following lines of "code" break my cloud-init config. Basically I am calling a son object as part of the DigitalOcean API which has a YAML format - I got most working but was able to narrow some errors I get down to these lines:

```
sed -i -n '/<Directory \/>/\{p;:a;N;/<\/Directory>/!ba;s/.*\n/    Options -Indexes\n    AllowOverride none\n    Require all denied\n/\};p'  /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf

sed -i -e '$a\ \n#Grant localhost  access to query or modify\nrestrict 127.0.0.1\nrestrict ::1' /etc/ntp.conf

sed -i -e '$a\ \n#Add local clock as backup\nserver 127.127.1.0\nfudge 127.127.1.0 stratum 10' /etc/ntp.conf
```

They all work fine if applied in the remote shell directly but tend to break if going through the DigitalOcean API (son object & YAML) - I assume I do not meet the YAML format but can't see what I missed to escape.

Any hints?

BTW: Looking at the cloud-init-output.log I can see that the created yam blob is written as following:

```
- sed -i -e '$a#Add local clock as backup
server 127.127.1.0
fudge 127.127.1.0 stratum 10' /etc/ntp.conf
```

This somewhat makes me think that I need to find way to escape the `\n` anyhow. Could this be the issue? how do I escape this?

Comment: What happens if you replace `\n` with \ followed by an actual newline ?

Comment: as yaml loves to eat multilines, I tried to avoid them (even if they can be used with '|' upfront I have bad experiences with that. However, I found that I got to escape any '\' twice, the first one gets eaten by the API and stored in cloud-init, so if I only got one backslash, the command won't run properly after gone through the DO API... if you have an appropriate word for that, let me know ;)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure you can specify mulitple commands as argument to runcmd but if you do you should make it a literal scalar in YAML:

```
runcmd: |
  sed -i -n '/<Directory \/>/\{p;:a;N;/<\/Directory>/!ba;s/.*\n/    Options -Indexes\n    AllowOverride none\n    Require all denied\n/\};p'  /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
  sed -i -e '$a\ \n#Grant localhost  access to query or modify\nrestrict 127.0.0.1\nrestrict ::1' /etc/ntp.conf
  sed -i -e '$a\ \n#Add local clock as backup\nserver 127.127.1.0\nfudge 127.127.1.0 stratum 10' /etc/ntp.conf
```

To see what a YAML parser makes out of this you can round-trip the yaml and test it. If the above is in a file `input.yml` then

```
  yaml rt input.yml
```

will complain if it cannot be round-tripped correctly¹.

Make sure you upload this data from a file, so that there are no aditional escape problems caused by the shell, (or python, perl etc)

---

¹ <sub>This was done using the `yaml` utility that comes with [ruamel.yaml](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ruamel.yaml) of which I am the author.</sub>